# phpmyadmin 2002 error with configuration failed setting

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

can someone help with phpmyadmin 2002 error and message below it saying
“Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed”

i am using xampp on win 7 64bit

it was working fine previously, i use xampp after one month and now it showing this error
can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure config.inc.php. It can be controluser username and password.

```
['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
['controluser'] = 'username';
['controlpass'] = '<your password>';
```

Find this fields in config.inc.php and make sure that this information are ok. If changed, restart XAMPP services.

Regards,
Hugo

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, but it doesn't work. still showing the 2002 error "The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured".